# Insert records into table from datasheet view form in access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have a command button on my main form that when clicked displays a datasheet view form for entering the data. I have written code before where I can add data from a single view form by adding a command button and executing the VBA code to insert values into the table.

When you have a datasheet view form, is there any way to do it differently? Also how do I create a new row automatically after the first has been entered. I am unable to enter more than 1 row at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datasheet form is an alternative view of a form as opposed to single and continuous. If your datasheet form has a control source and 'allows additions' then you should not need to have a button to add a record. The new record will automatically appear at the bottom of the datasheet with a * at the left.

Comment: so if it doesn't have a control source i.e. the fields on the form are unbound, this will not work

Comment: correct. The benefit of adding a control source and then bounding a text box is that you would not need to use vba to add the record.